# Python Docker API needs to know the syntax for attach(**kwargs) to container

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I am trying to run commands on a container like below:

```
# container started
container = PythonDockerAPIs.runContainerWithoutLogs(alpineImage, 'tail -f /dev/null', detach=True)
#execute the command
cmd1 = container.exec_run('ls -ltr',stream=True, detach=True)
```

Is there a way to attach the logs using `attach(**kwargs)` to this container and print the logs later on?

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html

Comment: anyone know the approach ?

Answer (score 1):

`**kwargs` just means the parameters listed are "keyword arguments", so for the [`attach` function](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.attach), it takes in these parameters (or "arguments") in any order using the form `keyword=value`:

- `stdout` (bool) – Include stdout.
- `stderr` (bool) – Include stderr.
- `stream` (bool) – Return container output progressively as an iterator
  of strings, rather than a single string.
- `logs` (bool) – Include the container’s previous output.

To call this function, you would do:

```
logs = container.attach(stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=True, logs=True)
```

Note that the documentation also states the [`logs`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.logs) function is a wrapper around the `attach` function, so you could use that function instead of `attach`.

### Edit:

Complete usage example:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run('hello-world', detach=True)

# method 1
print(container.logs())

# method 2
logs = container.attach(stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=False, logs=True)
print(logs)
```

Comment: I tried this and when I print logs and I see this error 
<docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0x10c044c90>

Comment: @user2511126 the documentation says if `stream=True`, the return value is an iterator of output strings, so you would need to iterate over the output, or set `stream=False`, or you could use the alternate function: [logs](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.logs)

Comment: for line in logs: print "-"+line I tried this but it prints nothing and hangs forever..

Comment: @user2511126 see my edit. I think the logs statement should come after you start the container, that way you have at least some log content.

Comment: I tried exactly that and the logs are empty when I print. (both methods)

Comment: @user2511126 I'm not sure what you're doing with the `runContainerWithoutLogs` function in your original question, but I just tried what I put (see second edit) in the Python REPL and it's working in Python 3.

Comment: hang on.. you have not used "exec_run" if you use exec_run with detach=true you wouldnt be able to print logs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189670/discussion-between-user2511126-and-kyle-falconer).